# Answers to new programmers

Tags: discussion

Can we add a button for walking a user through something.  The button would temporarily only allow comments and chats on the question.  Say for 15 min.  Giving people the opportunity to have time to ask leading questions to the requester.  I know the site is to provide answers to people, but I see a lot of questions where the person asking the question is missing a fundamental piece of information and once they have an answer, they are no longer interested in learning the thought process.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: what would clicking on that button do? The presence of a button is fun and cool. What's the functionality on buttonClick? :P

Comment: `once they have an answer, they are no longer interested in learning the thought process.` then let them walk away and go on being bad developers. Not our job to change their minds

Comment: This sounds kinda like __closing a question as unclear__.

Comment: Bad choice of words.  Once they have the answer, the opportunity to ask leading questions is gone, because they already have the answer without having to do any thinking.

Comment: And primarily:  Where this _button_ appears? At a question, out of nowhere?

Comment: How many people need to press your button for it to have an effect? How do you prevent abuse if it's just 1 or provide timely response if > 1? How do you prevent people from using comments to answer during the locked period?

Comment: I would suggest that this button be titled "close" as in "your question is very _close_ to being answerable". To prevent abuse, five reasonably experienced users would need to all click the button for this functionality to be engaged. Perhaps some kind of pre-filled prompt could allow the clickers to automatically leave basic advice as to what's missing in the question.

Comment: So... We should intentionally clutter up the site with bad, unclear, incomplete questions so that the community can puzzle over what in the world is going on, instead of just closing the question? And the goal of this is that lazy programmers can "have the answer without having to do any thinking?" *No thanks.*

Comment: How is this question "unclear"?  It was perfectly understandable to everyone making comments about its content and the ramifications of it..

Answer (score 8):

<s>Closure</s> Putting a question "on hold" is meant to be addressing this very issue.  What we want to do is put a moratorium on any new answers to a question until it can be brought up to standards.

There should be no difference in how we receive questions, regardless of who we receive them from.  It should not and does not matter if the person asking is a beginner, novice, or has 30 years of experience; they must all adhere to the same principle way of answering a question.

It may not add the convenience of being able to chat directly with the user to walk them through what their issue is, but if we've arrived at the point at which we **must** walk them through their question, something has already gone wrong.